# Why does isinstance() return False in this case?

Tags: python, python-3.x, constructor, memoization

I would like to write a decorator that allows memoiziation of a constructor. When I construct a class, I want the object returned from cache when possible.

The following code has been adapted from [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577998-cached-class/).

```
from functools import wraps


def cachedClass(klass):
    cache = {}

    @wraps(klass, updated=())
    class wrapper:
        def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            key = (cls,) + args + tuple(kwargs.items())
            try:
                inst = cache.get(key, None)
            except TypeError:
                # Can't cache this set of arguments
                inst = key = None
            if inst is None:
                inst = klass.__new__(klass, *args, **kwargs)
                inst.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
                if key is not None:
                    cache[key] = inst
            return inst

    return wrapper
```

A small test suite revals the following:

```
>>> @cachedClass
... class Foo:
...     pass
>>> f1 = Foo()
>>> f2 = Foo()
>>> f1 is f2
True
>>> Foo
<class 'cache.Foo'>
>>> type(f1)
<class 'cache.Foo'>
>>> isinstance(f1, Foo)
False
```

I expected that the last expression would return `True`. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7 and I do get `True`. However the interpreter also returns `<type 'instance'>` when I run `type(f1)`.

Comment: @HFBrowning because `class Foo: pass` is an old-style class in Python 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@cachedClass
class Foo:
    pass
```

is semantically equivalent to

```
class Foo:
    pass

Foo = cachedClass(Foo)
```

The `Foo` name is assigned the return value of `cachedClass`, which is the 
 `wrapper` class.

`wrapper` is in turn decorated by `functool.wraps` that copies `Foo`'s `__name__` attribute along with some other dunder attributes, so the `wrapper` class *looks* like `Foo`.

If you remove the `@wraps` line and print

```
print(type(f1), Foo, type(f1) is Foo, sep=', ')
```

you'll see that the `f1` is an instance of the original `Foo` class, but the `Foo` *name* now refers to the `wrapper` class, and they are different objects:

```
<class '__main__.Foo'>, <class '__main__.cachedClass.<locals>.wrapper'>, False
```

Comment: It's obvious now, thanks! I somehow must have thought that `isinstance` only checks `__name__` rather than `__class__`. Is there a simple way to make the wrapper *truly* transparent?